# how to embed swf in facebook

Tags: facebook, flash

I've been embedding my simple flash file in facebook and i haven't got any luck with it... when I echo text in it it shows... but the flash file itself doesn't... here's what I've done so far:

```
function handleLoginStatus(response) {
            if (response.session) { //Show the SWF                                      

                //A 'name' attribute with the same value as the 'id' is REQUIRED for Chrome/Mozilla browsers
                swfobject.embedSWF("textfla.swf", "newerFlash", "650", "700", "9.0", null, null, null, {name:"newerFlash"});

            } else { //ask the user to login                    

                var params = window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));                 
                top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+APP_ID+'&scope='+PERMS+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URI+params;                                     

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object tag to embed your flash file, just like-

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="textfla.swf" width="650" height="700">          
   <param name="wmode" value = "transparent" > 
</object>
```

Comment: no errors but no flash either :(.. I tried calling its php file in the browser and nothing shows..